# how to pass two variables value using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, stored-procedures

i am getting error while i am passing two variable value to stored procedure using linq

below is how i have used to pass variables to the linq

```
Customer objCustomer = DbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Customer>
                ("exec getCustomerDetails {0}{1}", CustomerId, OrderId).AsQueryable().ToList();
```

below is my stored procedure

```
create procedure getCustomerDetails 
@CustomerId int,
@OrderId int
as
select * from customer c
where c.CustomerId = @CustomerId and c.OrderId = @OrderId
```

below is the error i get

```
Message = "Must declare the scalar variable \"@p0@p1\"."
```

please suggest

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

further to what jackie has stated, I think the issue is down to the fact that there is no space between your parameters. try:

```
("exec getCustomerDetails {0} {1}", CustomerId, OrderId)
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanks for ur comment i have putted {0},{1} and now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a comma between {0} and {1}...

But why don't you [import the stored procedure into your entity model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231), so that you can call the stored procedure like this:

`DbContext.getCustomerDetails(CustomerId, OrderId)`

Comment: thanks for your comment but i don't want to move my stored procedure to enity model ...cuz i am assigning it to my customer class which have entities same as the my sql server customer table